# How to use SQL - ROW_NUMBER() function in Java Spring Boot JPA SQL-Query?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I want to write a query in Java Spring Boot persistence API,
the SQL query would look like this:

```
select useruuid, score, timeneeded, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(order by score desc, timeneeded) AS new_column 
from scores order by score desc, timeneeded;
```

I know how to write the Basic JPA Queries, but I haven't find
the function row_number, is there any ?

My question would be-
How to correctly use the `row_number` function in spring boot to set an Index over a sorted result list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it directly in JPQL when you start using Hibernate 6.

=> [Hibernate 6 with JPQL Window functions](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-jpql-window-functions/)